# Looking for practise problems on finding the solid angle of an object

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, book-recommendation

I would like to have a solid grasp on calculating the solid angle of an object, but my vector analysis course provides exactly two paragraphs regarding the subject, where the only example is a homework problem assigned to us.

Therefore where could I find a good collection of problems on calculating the angle (and why not more challenging applications of vector analysis as well), where the material contains illustrative figures, and model solutions that explain to the reader the why, what and how?

Comment: I don't think you could find a good collection of problems that require calculating a solid angle. However, if what you desire is a book that teaches you vector calculus, "Calculus - Early Transcedentals" by author James Stewart is a good book.

Comment: @IshraaqParvez Why is that?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my comment.

Comment: http://www.drdrbill.com/downloads/optics/photometry/Solid_Angle_Problems.pdf - may help.